# Ordering dates descending in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table in sqlite:

```
CREATE TABLE LICENSE (OBJECT_ID           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT,
                      LICENSE             BLOB NOT NULL,
                      NAME                VARCHAR(255), 
                      TYPE                VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      EXPIRATION_DATE     DATE,
                      CREATION_DATE       DATE NOT NULL)
```

I want to display all licenses, ordering them from the most recent to the oldest one. I use this simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM license order by date(CREATION_DATE) desc
```

Surprisingly the result is this (I only show you the creation_date column):

```
11 Sep. 2014 13-59-07
17 Sep. 2014 15-39-26
17 Sep. 2014 17-48-05
18 Sep. 2014 09-59-49
06 Oct. 2014 15-18-44
06 Oct. 2014 15-40-22
```

So I 've tried to replace desc by asc in my query but I get the very same result.

How can I get the right order?

Comment: SQLite does not have a real data type `date`. You can essentially store everything in a `date` column and the sorting is always done alphabetically, not based on a "real" date value.

Comment: Then why does '06 Oct. 2014 15-40-22' come after '11 Sep. 2014 13-59-07' ?

Comment: order by datetime(CREATION_DATE) DESC

Comment: I've tried that, it does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These strings are not in one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

It might be possible to use [substr()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) to extract the date fields, and [CASE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case), to replace the month strings with sortable numbers, but it would be a better idea to store the values in a proper format in the database in the first place.

Comment: That's it. The guy who has coded the app put the date in the database using a weird format. Dates were inserted through JDBC using setString and this weird format. Now, using setDate they are properly stored and can be ordered.